# Oracle Virtual Box Linux VM : virtual size vs actual size

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, disk-space, disk-encryption

I've just installed a fresh Kali version on Oracle Virtual Box.
To do so, I created a VM with 250Gb disk space, then ran the .iso : hence, the .vdi file size is 250Gb.
But when logged in, when I try - let's say - to unrar a file, the system claims that I don't have enough free space.

I checked in Virtual Box interface, and my actual and virtual sizes are almost the same : 250 Gb.

Besides, `gparted` shows a 250Gb **allocated** space (almost no free space).
[image]

Here you can see the result of `lsblk`.

[image]

And here you can see `df -h` result.

213Gb seem to be available (however, they are not shown in `gparted` !!)

During the Kali installation, I chose the disk encryption option (and the installer took a long time to write arbitrary bytes to prevent meta data leaks). But I remember having done this before, without having the problem I'm experiencing right now.

How can I get my space back ?

Any help appreciated !

Comment: shrinking a machine on Virtual Box is a mess...you have to fill free space with 0 and so on...

Comment: I assigned 250Gb space knowing that the VM is on a 1Tb HDD, with 500Gb free. Thanks I'll try this out, though that doesn't explain how to get the ```df -h``` 213Gb back ...

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation here is that your virtualizer (Virtual Box) created a *sparse* file of 250 GB of size, which only actually occupies the space that's actually been touched by data.

Now, your system actually tries to modify data, and because your *host* (not the guest) has run out of space on the volume that you store the disk image on has run out of free space, file operations fail.

Comment: Maybe, but why ```df -h``` shows available space ? I thought my problem came because of some kind of LUKS mechanism that shows my drive as full when I call ```gparted```

Comment: again, different levels. The VM has no idea of whether the virtualizer has space to write. That has, intentionally, been abstracted away.

Comment: ok I see what you mean. But what bothers me is that Kali shows 2 different things. I mean, it's aware of this amount of free space. When I click on properties for any file, I get : 30.9 GiB used (13%), 212.6 GiB free (87%).

Comment: again, no, Kali is *not* aware. To kali, the file on your host operating system looks like a disk that it can use just as if it was an actual disk. (please don't make me repeat this another time.)

Comment: @john that won't work with encryption, as the virtualizer intentionally can't see "inside" to see what blocks are all zero.

Comment: My Host uses Manufacturer offered encryption and VMs shrink easily.

Comment: yes, the *host* encrypts. But in Fafanellu's case, the storage encryption is done by the VM

Comment: @John seriously, no, the nicest virtualizer couldn't look through guest encryption and not store encrypted blocks that are "internally" empty, because they are *not* empty to the host.

Comment: @John "deviate from your requirements, and solve a different problem than you need to solve" is not really a solution ;)

Comment: @John no questions asked, that's really nice, but does in no way address OP's problem.

Comment: As I said, I did this before, without any troubleshooting, that was the reason why I posted my message. Anyways, thanks for your help, I'll perform a fresh install and I'll see if that happens again